# Springdoc Whitelabel Error Page with Spring V3

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to get swagger to run in my spring boot project. I'm currently using the spring verion `3.1.9`. I looked up so many guides that told me to just add `implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0"` to my `build.gradle` file and then everything works! Wrong! It doesn't. I get this White label error page every time:[white label error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsa4.png)

- I tried every URL.
- I configured springdoc in the `build.gradle` with some custom urls.
- I tried it with the old swagger dependencies

What I haven't tried is Spring-Security. But I don't want/need to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your configuration.

Let me give you a sample configuration which is working as expected for me

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
   dependencies {
//other dependencies
 implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0'
}
```

Swagger Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI myOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI();
    }


}
```

In Application Properites

```
springdoc.api-docs.groups.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.operations-sorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.writer-with-default-pretty-printer=true
springdoc.default-produces-media-type=application/json
springdoc.override-with-generic-response=true
```

Below property may be used when you need to proxy

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

I am able to see swagger is loading in below URL : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you create OpenAPI Bean? Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(
                        new Info()
                                .title("My app")
                                .version("1.0.0")
                );
    }
}
```